# Exaggerated CSS ease-in height transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

How would I be able to achieve the exaggerated ease-in height transition as seen in the dropdown menu transition of [this website](https://andreribeiro.co/)? [Normal CSS transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition_speed) are a lot more linear then what I am seeing rendered here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own custom easings using the [Cubic Bezier timing functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function#The_cubic-bezier()_class_of_timing_functions).

For instance, instead of the standard `linear` easing, you could do something like:

```
.selector {
    transition: right .5s cubic-bezier(.55,.04,.27,.91);
}
```

For an easy-to-use tool to make your own easings you can try [cubic-bezier.com](http://cubic-bezier.com/).

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you @agrm!

Comment: @Jimmy It really _is_ pretty amazing! :o)